# Does enabling GPU work for Integrated Graphics card?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

Is it that if we enable GPU in Render Properties then it works only in case of dedicated graphics card? Can it work in case of integrated graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it is not a question of integrated or dedicated, only of minimum requirements. For the general minimum requirements of Blender, have a look [here](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)
where it says

> Graphics card with 2 GB RAM, OpenGL 4.3

to run Blender at all and a list of supported graphics cards. But there is also a link specifically for *Cycles* [requirements](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). If you can find your integrated GPU there or know it fulfills the listed requirements, it should work. For example, for the AMD *HIP* option of *GPU Compute* it's stated that

> Both discrete GPUs and APUs are supported.

But well, to be realistic i believe you need a dedicated card (but others may prove me wrong).

Comment: I also think you would need a dedicated graphics card, for often the integrated cards' specifications are not good enough to give a significant improvement on render times over rendering with CPU. But since I do not know the OP's hardware I can't say anything definitely. I just know that I once had an old PC with old (dedicated) card where render times with GPU were slower than on my colleague's newer PC rendering with CPU, so it all depends.